# Meta key in Mac for Emacs

Tags: key-bindings

I have been working with GNU emacs on a Linux server but my keyboard is for mac.
I have a problem with defining the `alt` key as `meta`.
tried `(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)` in `~/.emacs.el` and then `eval-buffer` but still `esc` key worked as meta.

Comment: `esc` is bound separately to `meta` via the variable `meta-prefix-char`.  I personally have set that to `nil` for the past several years because I like having one additional modifier key.  The `alt` key defaults to `meta` on Windows and OSX builds of Emacs.  I'm not sure why it doesn't work on Linux out of the box.  Another forum participant will need to chime in.  If you are working in the terminal, instead of the GUI version of Emacs, that is also a factor.

Comment: `mac-command-modifier` (aka `ns-command-modifier)` is defined in `nsterm.m` and `ns-win.el`, and will *not* be available unless Emacs was built on an OSX platform `--with-ns`.

Comment: @lawlist thank you but i dont want to use `esc`.my problem is i use mac input keyboard but i work on linux system.

Comment: If you are running the Linux version of Emacs, are you running it through a terminal (Terminal, iTerm2, etc.) or are you running it through X11? If it's through a terminal then you need to tell the terminal, not emacs, to send the alt key as meta.

Comment: @amitp i connest to linux server with ssh and run emacs from Terminal.i havent access to terminal setting in server.

Comment: The server can't control the terminal settings. You'll need to go into your terminal app. If you're using Terminal, try Settings --> Profiles --> Keyboard --> Use Option as Meta key. If you're using iTerm2, try Settings --> Profiles --> Keys --> Left alt sends Meta (or Esc).